# Fancy Box and Booking Calendar - JQuery conflict in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I updated the Booking Calendar plugin on my WP site. It wasn't working due to an error with a script, and I fixed it using this solution: http://wpbookingcalendar.com/faq/loading-jquery-twice/

Problem is, editing out that line makes FancyBox not work anymore. I have updated FancyBox and JQuery Files, but still have the same problem: I have to choose between the Booking Calendar or the FancyBox to work, editing in or out that call to Jquery.

This is how the header of the page looks now. Is there anyway I can make both things work at the same time?

Thanks!

```
    <?php if ( is_page('Booking Calendar Name') ) { ?><?php wp_head(); ?><?php } ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.flow.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/init_form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/easySlider1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/dropdowns.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: is jQuery loading? because is commented out in your code

Comment: I think so. Reading Booking Calendar's solution you comment the line out to avoid repetition, therefore it should be being loaded with Book Calendar already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to view the source code on your site, it's hard to tell but what @JFK points out makes me think that there is no jQuery on your site unless you're on the page that utilizes the Calendar plugin. In either case, I would try de-registering the script and loading the one you want via your functions.php like this:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    if(!is_admin()) { 
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

You can remove the jQuery that is in your header since it will be loaded here instead.

Comment: But that's exactly the point from Booking Calendar (the one I linked first): you have to comment the jQuery line out to avoid duplication with Booking Calendar. It should be loading it once through Booking Calendar (first line in the code I pasted).

What you are saying is deleting the line from header.php and just add that function to Functions.php? Is that going to help with the duplication?

FYI: http://www.escapatealagateradevidrieros.com, sorry about that!

Comment: @aderojas : jQuery is not loading in that site (I don't even see bookingCalendar either)

Comment: Thanks for checking. Booking Calendar is in the line
<code><?php if ( is_page('Booking Calendar Name') ) { ?><?php wp_head(); ?><?php } ?> </code> and it's working, since www.escapatealagateradevidrieros.com/reserva-online shows it (you hve to first choose an option). If I uncomment the line, then the fancybox will work but the calendar won't show up.

Comment: @aderojas : Since you are using wordpress you should replace the alias `$` by `jQuery` otherwise you will get this js error `Timestamp: 29/11/2012 2:12:07 PM
Error: TypeError: $ is not a function
Source File: http://www.escapatealagateradevidrieros.com/wp-content/themes/lagatera/js/init_form.js
Line: 7`

Comment: @JFK damn, not so fast! It's only working in www.escapatealagateradevidrieros.com/reserva-online (where booking calendar actually shows up) so I still have to load the jQuery in the rest of the site! Can I do that directly from the function?

Comment: Taggin @ReLeaf in the hopes he can help now! I used your code above, but it seems to only work fine in the page where I'm loading booking calendar. Any idea why jQuery is not loading on the other pages? Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...Can you try adding <code><?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?></code> in your header just before the <code><?php wp_head(); ?></code> tag?

Comment: Thanks @ReLeaf, I tried and didn't seem to change anything :S I could always just make a diferente page-template.php for the rest of the site and add the call to jQuery there, but I would rather find a "global" solution.

Comment: No, I didn't... Thanks for seeing that, I was so focussed on the header I didn't see it! But that should be coming from functions.php. Maybe FancyBox needs it to be loaded in the header? In the page where booking calendar shows up the script is loaded within the header (I guess from Booking Calendar) but not within the footer. So... is there a way to for functions.php load that in the header?

Comment: It's all working for now. I created a page-template for the booking page adding the header there without the call to jQuery; I left the call to jQuery in the header affecting the rest of the site; I added the function provided by ReLeaf.... and I also deleted <code><?php wp_footer(); ?></code> from the footer. Two problems with this solution: the admin bar doesn't show up and when you edit the header you have to do it twice. Thanks both for your help so far, I'll keep trying to find a better solution but for now it's fine.

Comment: You can't delete <code><?php wp_footer(); ?></code>. You need that for many reasons.

Comment: I know, it's a temporary meassure until I get everything to work! I'll get back here when I figure it out to post the solution. Thanks!